# moq No setups configured error, how to quickly add a setup properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, moq, mstest

I have a unit test with moq in which I am getting an error that I need to do a setup, I do see examples, but everything is so different that I am wanting to do a a proper moq setup

Error:  "Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: called => called.SetWidgetResponseResponseData("searchType", It.IsAny())
No setups configured."

All 3 of these tests fail

```
[TestMethod]
public void it_should_call_set_response_response_data_on_the_view_reccount()
{
   view.Verify(called => called.SetWidgetResponseResponseData("recCount",It.IsAny<string>()));
}

[TestMethod]
public void it_should_call_set_response_response_data_on_the_view_searchtype()
{
  view.Verify(called => called.SetWidgetResponseResponseData("searchType", It.IsAny<string>()));
}

[TestMethod]
public void it_should_call_set_response_response_data_on_the_view_isgeosearch()
{
  view.Verify(called => called.SetWidgetResponseResponseData("isGEOSearch", It.IsAny<bool>()));
}
```

I think that the error is because "res" needs to be mocked with moq with a setup right?

```
if (res != null && res.Count > 0)
{ 

    View.SetWidgetResponseResponseData("recCount", res.Count.ToString());
    View.SetWidgetResponseResponseData("searchType", provFacSearchCrt.SearchType);
    View.SetWidgetResponseResponseData("isGEOSearch", provFacSearchCrt.IsGeoSearch);
}
```

Update

```
   public abstract class ProviderSearchPresenterContext :   Specification<Tc.Cbc.Presentation.ProviderSearchPresenter>
{
    protected Mock<ICESBaseWidgetView> view = new Mock<ICESBaseWidgetView>();
    protected Mock<ILookupServiceManager> lookupService = new Mock<ILookupServiceManager>(MockBehavior.Loose);
    protected Mock<ICAPProviderService> capProvider = new Mock<ICAPProviderService>(MockBehavior.Loose);
    protected Mock<IProviderFacilityServiceManager> prvFacServiceMgr = new Mock<IProviderFacilityServiceManager>(MockBehavior.Loose);
    //protected Mock<ProviderFacilitySearchCriteria> provFacSearchCrt = new Mock<ProviderFacilitySearchCriteria>(MockBehavior.Loose);
    protected Mock<ICESTraceManager> traceManager = new Mock<ICESTraceManager>();
    protected Mock<ILogger> logger = new Mock<ILogger>();
    protected Mock<IResourcesHelper> resources = new Mock<IResourcesHelper>();
    protected Mock<IUserContext> userContext = new Mock<IUserContext>();

    protected NameValueCollection QueryString = new NameValueCollection();
    protected NameValueCollection Form = new NameValueCollection();
    protected Dictionary<string, string> MethodArguments = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    protected override Tc.CES.Presentation.ProviderSearchPresenter construct()
    {
        //capProvider.Setup(x => x.GetProvider(It.Is<GetProviderReqMsg>(y => y.GetProvider.ProviderSystemIDs[0].SystemIDName == CESConstants.PROVIDER_ID 
        //    && y.GetProvider.ProviderSystemIDs[0].SystemIDValue == CESConstants.TZCOMMON))).Returns(new GetProviderRespMsg { 

        var presenter = new Tc.CES.Presentation.ProviderSearchPresenter(view.Object, traceManager.Object, logger.Object, resources.Object, 
            userContext.Object, lookupService.Object, capProvider.Object, prvFacServiceMgr.Object);
        presenter.QueryString = QueryString;
        presenter.Form = Form;
        presenter.MethodArguments = MethodArguments;
        return presenter;
    }

    protected override void given() { }

    protected override void when()
    {
        QueryString["ProFacSearch"] = "FACILITY";
        sut.ShowProviderSearch(null, null);
    }
}
```

The Specification class looks like this:

```
[TestClass]
public abstract class Specification<SUT>
{
    protected SUT sut;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        sut = construct();

        given();

        when();
    }

    protected abstract SUT construct();
    protected abstract void given();
    protected abstract void when();
}
```

Comment: If "view" is a mock, all your tests do is call a mocked object.  Mock objects are usually used to stub out external dependencies.  What exactly are you trying to test?

Comment: Could you please post all your code (TestInitialize) or at least where you create the view object ? Your test method should also contain code that calls the non-mocked code. Are your tests really this one line ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it.  I added a Setup like this:

```
this.prvFacServiceMgr.Setup(call =>     call.SearchProviderFacility(It.IsAny<ProviderFacilitySearchCriteria>())).Returns(new List<ProviderFacilitySearchResult>() 
        { 
            new ProviderFacilitySearchResult()
            { 
                ProviderName="TestProvider"
            } 
        });
```